# Independent front-end and back-end Application with Relay,React JS and Graphql Application

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

In my Project, we are using the React, Relay technologies from front-end, for service we are using Graphql technology.

Both are independent Applications.

Based on this https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-network-layer.html
Communicating the both frontend and backend.

Can you please give any sample for the network-layer application.

Answer (score 2):

Here a example: [link](https://github.com/nodkz/react-relay-network-layer/blob/master/examples/dataLoaderPerBatchRequest.js) Did you think of this?